# Unable to call aspx page web method using jquery ajax call?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Here is my ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function () {

         $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
             alert("I am in ?");
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "TestNew2.aspx/DisplayData",
                 data: "{}",
                 contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                 dataType: "text",
                 //success: function (msg) {
                 //    // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                 //    $("#btnSubmit").text(msg.d);
                 //    alert(msg.d);
                 //}


                 success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                     document.getElementById("lblOutput").innerHTML = xhr.responseText
                 },
                 error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                     alert(xhr.error);
                 }


             });
         });


     });
```

and my Web method`[WebMethod]
        public static string DisplayData()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }`

Getting aspx page when trying to call web method on aspx page.Here is the jQuery code
Can any one point out what may be wrong.Because the web method is not getting called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like

```
            $.ajax
                ({
                    url: " URL",

                    data: "{ 'name' : 'DATA'}",

                    dataType: "json",

                    type: "POST",

                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                   

                    async: true,

                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },

                    success: function (data) 
                    {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
```

OR

```
 jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Login.aspx/checkUserNameAvail",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{'iuser':'" + userid + "'}",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (msg) {
        $(msg).find("Table").each(function () {
            var username = $(this).find('UserName').text();
            if (username != '') {
                //window.location.replace('/iCalendar.aspx');
                alert('This username already taken..');
                $("#reguser").val('');
                $("#reguser").focus();
            }
            else {
            }
        });
    },
    error: function (d) {
    }
});
```

.CS

```
[WebMethod(enableSession: true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
    public static string checkUserNameAvail(string iuser)
    {
        try
        {
            iCalendarClass iC = new iCalendarClass();
            DataSet ds = iC.checkUserNameAvail(iuser);
            return (ds.GetXml());
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```